# react query invalidateQueries not update datalist

Tags: next.js, react-query

I have a test project, developed by next.js`14.0.3` and use react-query `^5.27.5` . I get data correctly by react query and my query is shown in react-query-devtools

[image]

I have two problems:

1- When i add a param to url my query is not shown in react-query-devtools:

[image]

2- Before i add param , del button on each result delete that  and list correctly updates by calling `queryClient.invalidateQueries` in delete success callback. but after adding param to url , list does not updates by calling `queryClient.invalidateQueries` after delete.

snippet code:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  return (
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
          <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

```
export default function Home() {
    const {push, query} = useRouter();
    const {page = 1, size = 10, ordering, z} = query;
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const {data: response, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, isFetching} = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['servers', {page:page}],
        queryFn: () => getServersService(),
        // staleTime:0,
    });

    const {data: deleteResponse, mutate, isSuccess: successDelete} = useMutation({
        mutationFn: (id: number) => deleteServerService(id),
        onSuccess: () => {
          queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['servers'] });
        },
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            {response?.data?.results?.map(a => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <div style={{width:'200px', display:'flex' , justifyContent:'space-between', marginBottom:"10px"}}>
                            {a.name}
                            <button onClick={() => {
                                mutate(a.id)
                            }}>del
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                    </>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I think that my two problems are related together. What is my code's bug??

Comment: I found problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75122016/2757573